# Fixing Grub, no partition

Tags: partitioning, ssd, bios, multi-boot, grub

So I made some foolish mistakes that confused my computer altogether. In trying to install a second os on the same ssd, and not liking the end result, for the graphical user interface of that os was missing, I deleted the partitions that I made for Kali Linux on windows. And in doing so, I am stuck with "no such partition Rescue" error.

I tried using a usb drive to install windows all over again, but with no luck there, for the computer was stuck loading the boot drive forever. I also reset the bios values to default, hope my usb would load this time, but again, no luck. Any help would be appreciated.

here is a link to show pictures of the boot files for both the usb drives that I tried to use; one is for ultimate boot cd, and the other is windows 10. both produced the same error. https://i.stack.imgur.com/YhGx0.jpg.

Answer (score 0):

The BIOS is perhaps not set to boot from USB.

If the USB does truly contain viable installation media for Windows,
try to hit the boot-selection key during the BIOS boot.
The possible keys are <kbd>F2</kbd>, <kbd>F12</kbd> and sometimes <kbd>Esc</kbd>.

If this doesn't work, enter the BIOS and ensure that the USB is the first in the boot
order. You will need to undo that once the Windows installation asks to be rebooted.

If the Windows installation can see your current Windows installation, choose
to upgrade it, rather than doing a new installation.

If it cannot find any Windows installation on the disk, I suggest to delete all
partitions, so the disk becomes one unallocated space, and let Windows install into
this space.

Comment: I'm sure, I burned the image file in the usb. whenever I do boot to the usb, it takes me to the grub terminal, but I will try to put the usb first in the sequence.

Comment: also how can I delete all partitions without an os

Comment: You can do that from the installation media when choosing the installation partition. I don't remember how that button is called, perhaps "Advanced".

Comment: I burned the image using my macOS's terminal.

Comment: Is it bootable? If not, please [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1627911/edit) your post and specify your method of burning.

Comment: It should be bootable. but even after burning an image of ultimate boot cd, I still face the same screen, "Welcome to grub, error: no such partition." Also, I changed the sequence so that the usb is booted first.

Comment: Could you email me, so that I may send you pictures?

Comment: Upload the images to https://imgur.com/ and edit the links into your post.

Comment: Done. two pictures of the boot files, and one fo the grub terminal.

Comment: I don't understand what is the problem. If the boot media that you created doesn't boot, then it was created wrong, or the BIOS is not set to boot from it. The BIOS is not Grub.

Comment: so how do i bypass grub. also, if you like, I can show you my bios boot menu just so you see that at least I am using the usb drive. maybe this will make you narrow down the situation.

Comment: Yes, please do that. There is no reason to enter Grub when booting from this media. Better also add how you created this boot media and was it done on Windows?

Comment: I thought of getting a ssd adapter and to format the ssd using my Mac, what do you think. Also I created the bootable usb using Mac following their guide:          https://www.lewan.com/blog/2012/02/10/making-a-bootable-usb-stick-on-an-apple-mac-os-x-from-an-iso.

Comment: Where did you get the ISO? I don't use the Mac, but I'm not sure about these instructions.

Comment: I got the iso from the windows official website. I added the image for the boot menu. you may check the images link again. –

Comment: The USB is truly listed, but the SanDisk 3.2 Gen11 is a flash key, not a real USB disk. What happens if you choose it for booting?

Comment: when I choose it, it takes me to the grub terminal. Also, I have another unbranded usb drive, with ultimate boot cd in it, and it doesn't make a difference.

Comment: Meaning it doesn't work. Either the key is unacceptable, or the method for writing it is incorrect. I suggest using a real USB disk and creating the boot on a Windows computer.

Comment: you mean a hard disk? I'm not clear on your last comment. Fortunately, I have access to a windows laptop. But please clarify for me.

Comment: I meant a real external disk, not a key.

Comment: It is an external disk.

Comment: Do you suppose I should just use Rufus on windows to burn the image on the SanDisk drive?

Comment: I usually use the [Windows 7 USB DVD Download Tool](https://filehippo.com/download_windows_usb_dvd_download_tool/). You may also use Microsoft's [Windows 10 Media Creation Tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10). If this doesn't work, then the SanDisk is unsuitable.

Comment: I managed to boot the Linux is using the sandisk usb, before the whole problem. But I burned that image using windows.

Comment: So two things happened. I decided to burn windows 10 in the sandisk usb drive, and ultimate boot cd in the other unbranded usb drive. both produced differences. with windows 10, the only difference was, I was asked to press any key to boot from usb. Then, after I follow that instruction I got "press any key to boot from USB" the same line is followed by "...GRUB loading" and I was back in ground zero where the error of no partition appears. with the ultimate boot cd, I was taken to a completely different terminal, with a different error, saying the kernel image was not found.

Comment: I found this solution for the kernel image error: https://www.pendrivelinux.com/error-could-not-find-kernel-image-linux/.    but I don't know what the directory should be exactly, because the syslinux.config exists. The website I linked to, also shows how my screen looked like.

Comment: To add regarding the kernel image issue. There are several syslinux.cfg files in the drive. if I only typed syslinux.cfg, which refers to the one that's not in any folder, in the terminal, next to "boot:" (check website link for reference). I would get invalid or corrupt kernel image. whereas if I typed the path to the other syslinux.cfg files, I would get "could not find kernel image." I will post the contents of the drive in imgur.

Comment: I managed to fix the problem by buying partedmagic, booting it, and deleting my ssd. I want to thank you nevertheless, for your persistence effort.

Answer (score 0):

having nothing important on the ssd, I got partedmagic, and booted its OS in my system. Then, I sanitised my ssd, and installed windows.

Note: If you want to get partedmagic to carry out a secure erasure, I must inform you that you might face an issue with your ssd being frozen. The product's website has a solution to this, but it didn't work for me. So I sanitized the ssd instead. Therefore, before getting any disk utility tool, I suggest that you compare your options.